# How can I perform the unmarshalling on a given xml (reserve engineering)

Tags: java, marshalling, unmarshalling, java-5

Down Below I have a method that handles the marshalling of a given Serializable event .what I want to achieve is to take the String result of this method and then recreate or rebuild  the event object, I have no Idea if this can be done using the Unmarshaller . could you please adivse

```
private String getTextOutOfSerializable(Serializable event)  {
        String myXmlString          = StringUtils.EMPTY;

        try {

             StringWriter stringWriter   = new StringWriter();
             Marshaller marshaller       = null;

             marshaller = new Marshaller(stringWriter);
             marshaller.setValidation(false);
             marshaller.marshal(event);
             myXmlString = stringWriter.toString();
        }catch(IOException e1){
            LOGGER.error(" getTextOutOfSerializable IOException  ",e1);
        }catch(MarshalException e2){
            LOGGER.error(" getTextOutOfSerializable MarshalException ",e2);
        }catch(ValidationException e3){
            LOGGER.error(" getTextOutOfSerializable ValidationException ",e3);
        }


        return myXmlString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JAXB. To Marshal:

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 JAXB.marshal(javaObject, sw);
```

And for unmarshaling use:

```
  JavaObject unmarshal = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(string), JavObject.class);
  System.out.println(unmarshal.property);
```